# Nextjs 13 set to full client side rendering config

Tags: javascript, next.js, next.js13

Is there a config for NextJS 13 to use full client side rendering only? ie. I do not want to use default server side rendering.

Comment: So use React then

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: **No there is not.**

Also, if there was, it would defy the purpose of using Next.js at all, because that is not what it was designed for. If you need a client-side only application you are probably better off using something like [create-react-app](https://create-react-app.dev).

---

If you still want to give server-side rendering a shot and need some client side logic to run, like state or effects you can always add the `"use client"` directive at the top of your component' file to opt-in into client side rendering.